# 10.0.0.1 is non-routable IP v4 address but it is routable over the Internet

Tags: networking, ipv4

Strange but this is happening to me I have checked on multiple machines but on the same network. IP v4 address - 10.0.0.1 is routable! see attached screenshot and suggest why this is happening. since this is an non-routable IP address.

Please see the Traceroute and Ping result on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your ISP (hathway) is using [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) and has some strange routing configured on it's local network.

Comment: If  your traffic is leaving the 10.* subnet, and going via 208.* of similar, then you're certainly NOT on the same network anymore. 10.* is reserved for private use. You appear to communicate with 10.0.0.1 over a VPN or something like that.